# unable to get the click/change event on checkbox which is configured with jquery-checkbox-switch pluggin

Tags: jquery-plugins, checkbox

I applied jquery switch checkbox plugginhttps://github.com/olance/jQuery-switchButton) on my checkbox , but i am unable to get the change or click event on it. Here is the html page.

```
         <script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#check").CheckboxSwitch();
        $("#second").hide();
        $("#first").hide(3000);
        $("#second").show(5000);

        $('#check').click(function () { $("#second").hide(); $("#first").show(3000); });
        $('#check').change(function () { $("#second").show(); $("#first").hide(3000); });
    });


</script>
```

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox"  value="" />

<div id="first">
    Some textSome text
    Some text
    Some textSome text
    Some textSome textSome text
    Some text
    Some textSome text
    Some textSome textSome text
    Some text
    Some textSome text
    Some textSome textSome text
    Some text
    Some textSome text
    Some textSome textSome text
    Some text
</div>

<div id="second">

    Second div tagaSecond div tagaSecond div 

</div>
```

How to get the click or change event on checkbox which is enabled with checkbox-switch pluggin.

Answer (score 0):

With that plugin you are not clicking the inpunt and also the value is not changing.
look the documentation of the pluging and check if your are able to handle the event onChenge.

Other option is do it manually.
Handler the onClick event of $('.switch-button-background').click(.... and $('.switch-button-button').click(....   Thats the real items your clicking.

You can check the state of the control checking the att style of .switch-button-button if left = -1 the OFF el ON, or you can create a new varible and set the value in the functions onclick describes above.

Hope this helps you.